# Create a copy of an empty dataframe and assign values to it based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with single or multiple entries for a member. I want to select all entries for a member and copy it into an empty dataframe (below).

```
n   member_id          signup_date  cancel_date checkout_date
1   669991797608307338  2014-10-22  2015-04-03  2014-10-27
2   669991797608307338  2014-10-22  2015-04-03  NaT
3   669991797608307338  2014-10-22  2015-04-03  NaT
4   669991797608307338  2014-10-22  2015-04-03  NaT
5   669991797608307338  2014-10-22  2015-04-03  NaT
261 -216296171696241227 2018-04-30  NaT         NaT
262 740140472387380715  2018-04-30  NaT         NaT
263 -973878985384418370 2018-04-30  NaT         NaT
264 -600987750910073333 2018-04-30  NaT         NaT
265 -926101607852327555 2018-04-30  NaT         NaT
```

... and copy the entries into a dataframe for each member_id.

```
index = pd.date_range('2014-10-22', end='2018-04-30')
columns = ['signup','checkout','cancel']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

```
  (index)       signup  checkout  cancel
2014-10-22       0         0       0
2014-10-23       0         0       0
2014-10-24       0         0       0
2014-10-25       0         0       0
2014-10-26       0         0       0
```

What function / method is the most efficient to use to select by member_id?
E.g. if signup_date = 2014-10-22 then there should be a 1 in the copy of the dataframe for the specific member. If the checkout_date = 2014-10-27 a 1 should be in the checkout column on the 2014-10-27 row.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very complicated solution. I create a list of tuples ("member_id", df2_like):

```
drng=pd.date_range('2014-10-22', '2018-04-30')

lrslt=[ (member,pd.DataFrame({"signup": drng.isin(grp.signup_date), \
                              "cancel":drng.isin(grp.cancel_date), \
                              "checkout":drng.isin(grp.checkout_date)}, \
                    index=drng).astype(int) ) \

         for member,grp in df.groupby("member_id") ]
```

**Edit:** Extending the (member,member_df) tuples in "lrslt":

```
new_lrslt= [ (member,mdf,mdf.resample("Y").sum(),mdf.resample("W").sum()) for (member,mdf) in lrslt ]
```

Comment: this is good! I would like as a next step like to do an aggregation by week. probably by adding a column for year and another one for month from the `drng` datetime index. and then `groupby(['year', 'week']).sum()` for each member. There could be more than 1 checkouts per week but max. 1 signup or cancel in a week. Not sure how I can access these and create the columns for each member though?

Comment: `dict(tuple(df.groupby('member_id')))` or `list(tuple(df.groupby('member_id')))`

Comment: I used the code but it does still having one entry per day and not per week, see output: `(-999608131177886396,             signup  checkout  cancel
2014-10-22       0         0       0
2014-10-23       0         0       0
2014-10-24       0         0       0
2014-10-25       0         0       0
2014-10-26       0         0       0
...            ...       ...     ...
2018-04-26       0         0       0
2018-04-27       0         0       0
2018-04-28       0         0       0
2018-04-29       0         0       0
2018-04-30       0         0       0
`

Comment: We haven't got member id '-999608131177886396' in the test data. Please, present the expected output with data known to me. 'new_lrslt' contains the weekly aggregated data.

Comment: ok sorry it is alright and makes sense, the firs part is by day, and in the second part it is aggregated by week.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to `df2` and for each date count the number of unique `member_id` in `df` and for each of sign, cancel and checkout columns.

Something like this:

```
df2["signup"] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.where(df["signup_date"] == x.name).member_id.nunique(), axis=1)
```

In this lambda expression, we filter `df` where the `signup_date` equals the `DatetimeIndex` of `df2`(accessed by `row.name`) and count distinct members.

You can do the same for the 2 other columns :

```
df2["cancel"] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.where(df["cancel_date"] == x.name).member_id.nunique(), axis=1)
df2["checkout"] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.where(df["checkout_date"] == x.name).member_id.nunique(), axis=1)
```

Output: (with your input example)

```
            signup  checkout  cancel
2014-10-22       1         0       0
2014-10-23       0         0       0
...            ...       ...     ...
2014-10-27       0         1       0
...            ...       ...     ...
2015-04-03       0         0       1
2018-04-30       5         0       0
```

**NOTE:** While this gives correct results, I'm actually not sure about the performances for large dataframes.

**EDIT:**

To do the same as above but for every `member_id`, you can loop throught the original dataFrame, like this :

```
df_list = list()
for member_id in df["member_id"].unique():
    d = df2.copy()
    d["signup"] = d.apply(lambda x: df.where((df["signup_date"] == x.name) & (df["member_id"] == member_id)).member_id.nunique(), axis=1)
    d["cancel"] = d.apply(lambda x: df.where((df["cancel_date"] == x.name) & (df["member_id"] == member_id)).member_id.nunique(), axis = 1)
    d["checkout"] = d.apply(lambda x: df.where((df["checkout_date"] == x.name) & (df["member_id"] == member_id)).member_id.nunique(), axis = 1)

    df_list.append({"member_id": member_id, "statistics_by_date": d})
```

It gives a list of: `{"member_id": <string>, "statistics_by_date": <DataFrame>}`

Comment: thank you for the answer. Sorry if my question was not so clear. I want to go through every member_id one by one and for each I make a copy of the empty df2, and insert the actions (1 or 0) for signup, checkout and cancel by using the date time index. I'm new to python and I have spent a lot of time figuring out a solution.

Comment: can you explain me the `x.name` expression? where does the `name` come from?

Comment: @superflow `x.name` is the the index of the row `x` (here it's the `DatetimeIndex`)